# How can you test for a boolean value inside a Map?

Tags: java

I am new to java so please go easy on me. I have a hashmap which contains String keys and Boolean values like the following.

```
Map<String, Boolean> states = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
states.put("b_StorageAvailable", true);
states.put("b_StorageWritable", true);
```

Which I am returning from a function. Once I get this somewhere else, I would like to be able to call an if statement on one of these to see if its true or false.

```
if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable")) { 
    //Do this 
}
```

But java keeps showing me that I need this to be a Boolean type, and it is a Map type. How can I do this easily?

**UPDATE**

It should be noted that the code I am calling the function with and getting the return value looks like this,

```
Map states = this.getExternalStorageStatus();
```

Comment: Have you considered using a Set<String>?

Comment: It works fine for me on eclipse using Jdk 1.6

Comment: Apart from the fact that your `}` is inside a comment, my compiler/IDE has no problems with your code

Comment: I just saw your update: `Map` is quite different from `Map<String, Boolean>`

Comment: @adrian lol thats not actually what my code looks like....i just put that here for description purposes. I fixed it now just for you :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Just make sure you're using exactly the same key (`"b_StorageAvailable"`). Because the `Boolean` in the `Map` is auto-boxed to a primitive boolean, if there is no entry in the `Map` for the supplied key, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

I would also check that your function's return type and the local variable are defined as `HashMap<String, Boolean>` as well. If it is untyped, then you won't be able to assume it's a `Boolean` in the `Map`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Boolean> states = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    states.put("b_StorageAvailable", true);
    states.put("b_StorageWritable", true);

    if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable")){ // works fine!
        System.out.println("storage is available!");
    }

    Map states2 = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); // untyped!
    states.put("b_StorageAvailable", true);
    states.put("b_StorageWritable", true);
    if(states2.get("b_StorageAvailable")){ // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to boolean
        System.out.println("storage is available!");
    }

}
```

So all you need to do is change

```
Map states = this.getExternalStorageStatus();
```

to

```
Map<String, Boolean> states = this.getExternalStorageStatus();
```

And potentialy change the return type of `getExternalStorageStatus()`

```
private Map<String,Boolean> getExternalStorageStatus(){
 ...
}
```

Comment: The return type is Map. Should it be HashMap? You can see on there, that my states is a Map type.

Comment: Changing the return type to HashMap, and the states type to HashMap does not fix the error.

Comment: Note that there's still the potential for not getting back a value, which could result in a NullPointerException.  This needs to be checked for.  Please refer to my answer for a one-liner to appropriately handle this.

Comment: Okay got it! I changed the return type to Map<String, Boolean>, and the retrieving variable to Map<String, Boolean> states = getExternalStorageStatus() and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're on Java 5 or newer (which you must be, given the demonstrated use of Generics):

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(states.get("b_StorageAvailable"))){
   //Do this
}
```

Comment: I tried putting that but netbeans shows it as an error. I did not however try and run it yet :p

Comment: If it doesn't work, please include the description of the error that it is showing.

Comment: Your error could be due to mismatched braces - try doing `if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable") == true) { /* Do this */ }`

Comment: mprabhat's answer, though currently syntactically incorrect, raises another good point - you need to also check for null values, as in no value has been stored.

Comment: My original answer successfully compiled and executed under Eclipse with Java 1.6.  However, I've also updated it to account for null values, and it also tested successfully.

Comment: I think im using Java 1.7. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Now that you've updated your question, +1 for Hound Dog's answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable"))
```

You are tyring to fetch the value stored against the key `b_StorageAvailable`

changing it to like this :

```
if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable")) != null {
   //Do your task check if the boolean is false or not
}
```

will get you going or the simplest

```
if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable") != null && states.get("b_StorageAvailable").booleanValue()) {
   //Do your task 
}
```

in case you want to check if your map contains a specific key you can check that if `map.containsKey` API

Comment: Warning: `if(states.get("b_StorageAvailable")) != null)` will evaluate to `true` even if the value in the `Map` is `false`.

Comment: @Asaph: His point is a valid precaution. What if the mapping is not available for the key provided? It will eventually lead to a `NullPointerException` while (auto) unboxing the boolean value using `.booleanValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine, I wrote the test code below and it passed. You may also want to ensure you're spelling the key values correctly, and test to make sure the key is valid using containsKey. I wrote the following test code and it passed.

(As an additional suggestion you may also want to refactor your States Map into a proper Class as I did below. I avoid passing around Maps whenever possible.)

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

public class StatesTest {

    @Test
    public void testStates() {
        Map<String, Boolean> statesMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        statesMap.put("b_StorageAvailable", true);
        statesMap.put("b_StorageWriteable", false);

        States states = new States(statesMap);

        assertTrue(states.isStorageAvailable());
        assertTrue(states.isStorageWriteable() == false);
    }
}

class States {
    private boolean storageAvailable;
    private boolean storageWriteable;
    // etc

    public States(Map<String, Boolean> states) {        
        if (states.containsKey("b_StorageAvailable")) {
            storageAvailable = states.get("b_StorageAvailable");
        }

        if (states.containsKey("b_StorageWriteable")) {
            storageWriteable = states.get("b_StorageWriteable");
        }
    }

    public boolean isStorageAvailable() {
        return storageAvailable;
    }

    public boolean isStorageWriteable() {
        return storageWriteable;
    }
}
```